# How to move huge amount of data from one page to another page without state management

Tags: asp.net

I have a scenario, where I have three ASP.Net web pages below,

1. First page have a textbox to contain the huge data and the next button to go to the second page.
2. The second page also contains a textbox to contain huge data with previous to go back the first page and next button button to go third page.
3. The third page also contains a textbox to contain huge data and previous button to go back to second page and a submit button to save it.

The data which textbox contains is huge. How do I maintain these data on the postbacks and save it to the database without using any state management features?

Comment: What is "huge" in your case?

Comment: You can use `Server.Transfer` or a `LinkButton.PostBackUrL` to post to the second page. Then you can access the first page with all it's controls via `Page.PreviousPage`. Just cast it accordinlgy or use `FindControl`.

Comment: @Grumbler85 : the data could be in hundreds of MB.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : thanks, but what about to access the data of first page in third page?

Comment: What about using jQuery and some sort of Wizzard-Plugin?

Comment: @Grumbler85 : this was the exactly my first suggestion on mind, but i can't use the wizard control even of asp.net.

Comment: I'm not speaking of the wizzard control in .NET but an jQuery-Plugin which makes you a wizzard out of some divs.

Comment: i misunderstood, i have no idea about jQuery-Plugin wizzard. Do you have any help url for wizzard-plugin to get the answer for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Without state management of any kind, the only option is to use hidden fields for every textbox on all the pages. The first page would include hidden fields for fields two and three, and so on. Since you indicate the data could be 'hundreds' of MBs, that doesn't sound like a smart option.

1. What is your reason to want no state management?
2. Why are you editing hundreds of MBs on a web page in a text editor?

Comment: As i mentioned, i cant use state management features at all. one of my team member asked me this question. After exploring the net, i did not get any answer. so, thought i can get the answer in SO.

Comment: Like I said, without state management, the only option is to use hidden fields.